# Validate User Input Using Java Chars and Strings

Tags: java, string, chars

I have seen this asked 2x, but the correct response I need has not been addressed.

In this assessment,
 you will design and code a Java console application that
 validates the data 
entry
  of a course code (like IT4782)
 and 
report
 back if the
 course code is valid or
 not
 valid.
 The 
application 
uses the Java char
 and 
String data types to implement
 the validation.
 You 
can 
use 
either
 the
  Toolwire environment
 or your
 local 
Java
 development
 environment
 to complete this 
assignment.

The requirements of
 this application are 
as follows:
 The application is to read 
a course code 
entered 
by the user
 from the
 keyboard.
 The course code
 is made 
of 5 characters and should 
follow
these

Rules:

- First
  character
  is  always
  an 
  upper
  case I
  or a lower
  case i
- Second character
  is always an upper
  case
  T or
  a lower
  case t
- Third,
  fourth,
  fifth,
  and sixth characters
  are always digits (0-
  9) 
  The application then validates the course code against
  above the rules and prints a
  message

If the
course code 
is valid
 or not.
 If the course code is not
 valid,
 the application should print
 a message 
explaining why
 the course 
code is not
 valid.

Output should look like this:
[image: Output should look like this]

Here is my code, I cannot get the code to produce the pictured results. It outputs all the invalid messages.

```
package u4a1_validatecoursecode;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class U4A1_ValidateCourseCode {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Larry Copy
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a course code to validate (e.g. IT4782) : ");
        String code = s.nextLine();
        if (validateCode(code)) {
            System.out.println("Course code: " + "" + code + "" + " is valid.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not valid code");
        }
    }

    private static boolean validateCode(String code) {
        if (code.length() != 6) {
            return false;
        } else {
            //First character is always an upper case I or a lower case i
            if (code.charAt(0) != 'I' && code.charAt(0) != 'i') {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("integer is not an I or i");

            // Second character is always an upper case T or a lower case t
            if (code.charAt(1) != 'T' && code.charAt(1) != 't') {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("integer is not a T or t");

            // Third, fourth, fifth, and sixth characters are always digits (0-9)
            if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(2))) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("integer 3 is not a number");

            if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(3))) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("integer 4 is not a number");

            if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(4))) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("integer 5 is not a number");

            if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(5))) {
                return false;
            }
            System.out.println("integer 6 is not a number");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your `return` before the print, once you return you're exit function scope

Comment: one more point you are always returning false... this method will never return true

Comment: Thanks all for the help... I have been at this for about 5 hours trying to figure out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you `return false;` the code after is not executed so you'll never see why it returns
2. If you return only `false` the test will never pass, you need a variable to validate or not the `code`
3. If it goes in one `if` (not valid) you'll get the message, and the `valid` will be `false`

---

```
private static boolean validateCode(String code) {
    if (code.length() != 6) {
        return false;
    } else {
        boolean valid = true;
        //First character is always an upper case I or a lower case i
        if (code.charAt(0) != 'I' && code.charAt(0) != 'i') {
            System.out.println("integer is not an I or i");
            valid = false;
        }
        // Second character is always an upper case T or a lower case t
        if (code.charAt(1) != 'T' && code.charAt(1) != 't') {
            System.out.println("integer is not a T or t");
            valid = false;
        }
        // Third, fourth, fifth, and sixth characters are always digits (0-9)
        if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(2))) {
            System.out.println("integer 3 is not a number");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(3))) {
            System.out.println("integer 4 is not a number");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(4))) {
            System.out.println("integer 5 is not a number");
            valid = false;
        }
        if (!Character.isDigit(code.charAt(5))) {
            System.out.println("integer 6 is not a number");
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is giving me an error and wants to add this Boolean valid = false, where you have it at the beginning = true. If I add as suggested, it returns "Not valid code" on anything I enter.

Comment: @larrys what error ? I tried with IT4782 and it works for me , did you copy exactly my answer ?

Comment: I started a new project and pasted what you provide, and thank you for the assistance. @private static Boolean XXXXX (for me line 19) error says illegal start of expression

Comment: Got it, Thank you. I figured out what I was doing incorrectly when I was pasting it back.

Answer (score 0):

You are using too much line of code:
Here what I do:

```
   private static boolean validateCode(String code,String validCode) {
        boolean b=true;
        if (code.length() != 6) {
            return false;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<code.length();i++){
            if(code.toLowerCase().charAt(i)!=validCode.toLowerCase().charAt(i) && i<2){
                System.out.println("Character at "+i+" position is not an "+ validCode.charAt(i));
                b= false;
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(code.charAt(i)) && i>2){
                System.out.println("Character at "+i+" is not a digit");
                b= false;
            }
        }
    return b;
    }
```

Comment: same error, illegal start of expression, I am sensing I am not doing something correctly on my end

Comment: Got it, Thank you. I figured out what I was doing incorrectly when I was pasting it back.